# Why does scala call the method passed to println before printing the line it is called in?

Tags: scala, function

The program looks like this ...

```
object Delay{

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        delayed(time())
    }

    def time()={
        println("Getting time in nanoseconds : ")
        System.nanoTime
    }

    def delayed(t: => Long)={
        println("In delayed Method")
        println("Param : "+t)
    }
}
```

And the output is ...

```
    In delayed Method
    Getting time in nanoseconds :
    Param : 139735036142049
```

My question is why does the word "Param :" print after the "Getting time ..." and not like,

```
    In delayed Method
    Param : 
    Getting time in nanoseconds : 139735036142049
```

Comment: delayed needs time to be executed before it can do what it does

Comment: You could rewrite this as `val t = time()` and then `delayed(t)`

Comment: @mfirry why would you though? This doesn't make the code more readable or efficient in any way (in fact I'd argue that labeling something vague like `t` makes code less readable).

Comment: I was just trying to explain why time gets executed before delayed

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you see this execution order, is because `t` is a **by-name parameter** in your code:

```
def delayed(t: => Long)
```

If you defined your `delayed` method with a **by-value** parameter like so:

```
def delayed(t: Long)
```

the `time()` function would have been evaluated **before** the call to `delayed`, and you would get the following output instead:

```
Getting time in nanoseconds : 
In delayed Method
Param : 139735036142049
```

The trick is that **by-name** parameters are called **only** when they're used, and **every time** they're used. From the [Scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html):

> By-name parameters are only evaluated when used. They are in contrast to by-value parameters.
>
> By-name parameters have the advantage that they are not evaluated if they aren’t used in the function body. On the other hand, by-value parameters have the advantage that they are evaluated only once.

Comment: thanks - you are right I missed the first `println` from the `delayed` function

Answer (score 0):

`t/time` value will be evaluated before printing param.
so it prints `println("Getting time in nanoseconds:")`
before printing `println("Param : "+t)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, does it happen in other languages like C, C++, Java also? or just in scala?

Comment: In Java, it is based on which version you use Java 8+ supports lambda and allows passing function as param.

Answer (score 0):

---

IMHO the current scala doc, within the link provided by Zoltan, is misleading and confusing. By-name parameters have the advantage of repetitive read / call / evaluation, and are used mainly for that purpose. The delayed evaluation has to do with lazy vals, that is a different topic. The delayed evaluation of by-name, when passed as var / closure / anonymous_function, is just a collateral effect of the repetitiveness - given as an example, in the same scala doc, under the from of a whileLoop example.

By-name parameter behavior depends on what you pass as actual param -

- if you pass a val(ue)/constant  it will be evaluated in advance,
- if you pass a var its value will be read each time the by-name is
  referenced by the runtime code
- if you pass a closure / anonymous_function it will get called each
  time the by-name is referenced by the runtime code

.

```
def two[A](a: => A): List[A] = List(a, a) // two references

def two_iter[A](a: => A) { (1 to 2) foreach { x => a } } // two references 

def two_lazy[A](a: => A) = { lazy val b = a; List(b, b) // one lazy reference

def two_delayed[A](a: => A): List[A] = { val l = List(a); Thread.sleep(5000); a :: l } // two references with delay 


val x = 5; two(5); two(x) // (5, 5) only once

var z = 5; val f = Future { two_delayed(z) }; Thread.sleep(1000); z += 1; f.onSuccess { case result => println(result)  } // (6, 5) two reads 

two { println("in"); 5 } // (5, 5) called twice

var t = 0; two { println("in"); t += 1; t } // (1, 2) called twice

two_iter { println("in"); 5 } // called twice 

two_lazy { println("in"); 5  } // (5, 5) called once
```

Comment: I just discovered that I have to put whatever character after the list (a dot), otherwise the code won't format as code (I suppose it gets formatted as a continuation of the last item of the list).