# What is the order of printing in scala println() when there is a function call inside println()?

Tags: scala

I am new to programming. I have the following scala code.

```scala
object callByName{
 def time():Double={
    println("Getting time in nanoseconds");
    System.nanoTime;
}

def delayed(t: =>Double):Unit={
    println("In delayed method");
    println("Param: "+t);
}

def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    delayed(time());
}
```

}

And its output is as follows.

```
In delayed method
Getting time in nanoseconds
Param: 1.20042899366066E15
```

I am curious why "Getting time in nanoseconds" prints before "Param:" prints? I mean why the output is not as follows?

```
In delayed method
Param: Getting time in nanoseconds
1.20042899366066E15
```

Comment: Because `t` gets evaluated before the second `println` in `delayed runs.

Comment: Check out this thread, it answers the exact same question from someone using the same functions as you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184830/why-does-scala-call-the-method-passed-to-println-before-printing-the-line-it-is